# Parsing JSON on Android Using -> ( Retrofit2 + Jackson )

Tags: android, jackson, retrofit

does somebody have idea or a good website for getting large Json in android using retrofit2+jackson ?

one more question : is Jackson really faster than Gson ?!

Comment: is that enough for you https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos     and retrofit complements moshi

Comment: thanks, it was beautiful :) , but i have 6 tables to Download

Comment: I googled and found Jackson is much faster than Gson when using with retrofit, so I'm looking for fastest way, I've got more than 100000 records.

Comment: no such thing, even gson performs slightly better in some cases, stick with library who comes from same company, here moshi and retrofit both come from square family.

Comment: Even retrofit has its own Jackson , I'm wondering there is no even one website to explain simple getting json using retrofit with its Jackson!!!

Comment: could you please help me how to receive this json using retrofit and moshi :   {
    "fields": [
        {
            "id": 108,
            "name": "Advertising"
        },
        {
            "id": 105,
            "name": "Writing"
        }
    ],
    "popular": [
        {
            "id": 44,
            "name": "Graphic Design"
        },
        {
            "id": 132,
            "name": "UI/UX"
        }
    ],
    "http_code": 200
}

Comment: give me a moment,  I'll provide a sample in java

Comment: Thanks a million bro :)

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, I was working on other, I'll upload now

Comment: Thank you bro , finally I found it right now how it works , and I'm working on it , thank you verrrrrrry much dear notTdar

Comment: Exactly at the same time you sent message I was trying if it works and thanks god and thank you it works now :)

Comment: glad, anyway I already posted, you can mark it solve or delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UserSimple

```
public class UserSimple {

    @Json(name = "fields")
    private List<Field> fields = null;
    @Json(name = "popular")
    private List<Popular> popular = null;
    @Json(name = "http_code")
    private Integer httpCode;

// getter and setter
}
```

Popular.class

```
public class Popular {

    @Json(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Json(name = "name")
    private String name;

    // getter and setter
}
```

Filed.class

```
public class Field {

    @Json(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Json(name = "name")
    private String name;

        // getter and setter

}
```

and lastly

```
private void mapFromJson() {
        Log.d(TAG, "mapFromJson: ()++++++");


        String jsonString = "{\n" +
                "   \"fields\":[\n" +
                "      {\n" +
                "         \"id\":108,\n" +
                "         \"name\":\"Advertising\"\n" +
                "      },\n" +
                "      {\n" +
                "         \"id\":105,\n" +
                "         \"name\":\"Writing\"\n" +
                "      }\n" +
                "   ],\n" +
                "   \"popular\":[\n" +
                "      {\n" +
                "         \"id\":44,\n" +
                "         \"name\":\"Graphic Design\"\n" +
                "      },\n" +
                "      {\n" +
                "         \"id\":132,\n" +
                "         \"name\":\"UI/UX\"\n" +
                "      }\n" +
                "   ],\n" +
                "   \"http_code\":200\n" +
                "}";

        Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
        JsonAdapter<UserSimple> jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(UserSimple.class);

        try {
            UserSimple userSimple = jsonAdapter.fromJson(jsonString);
            Log.v(TAG, "mapFromJson2: " + Objects.requireNonNull(userSimple).toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "mapFromJson:   ---- ");

    }
```

This should help.

Comment: Thank you very very much:) and thanks a lot for your time. God bless you